# CoreData - TableView does not get updated

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, save, nsfetchrequest

So, I'm struggling to learn how to handle CoreData properly.

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class IngredientsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {

    let moc = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
    var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController?


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchIngredients(), managedObjectContext: moc!, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
        fetchedResultsController?.delegate = self
        fetchedResultsController?.performFetch(nil)

    }

    func fetchIngredients() -> NSFetchRequest {

        var fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "DetailsForRecipe")
        let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "ingredients", ascending: true)

        fetchRequest.predicate = nil
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
        fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 20

        return fetchRequest

    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return fetchedResultsController?.sections?[section].numberOfObjects ?? 0
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ingCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
        if let ingCell = fetchedResultsController?.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? DetailsForRecipe {
            cell.textLabel?.text = ingCell.ingredients
        }
        return cell
    }
}
```

and

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class SingleIngredientViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var ingField: UITextField!
    var moc = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    @IBAction func addIng(sender: AnyObject) {

        let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("DetailsForRecipe", inManagedObjectContext: moc!)
        let details = DetailsForRecipe(entity: entityDescription!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: moc)
        details.ingredients = ingField.text

        var error: NSError?
        moc?.save(&error)

        if let err = error {
            var status = err.localizedFailureReason
            println(status)
        } else {
            println("Ingredient \(ingField.text) saved successfully!")
        }

        if let navigation = navigationController {
            navigation.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
        }
    }
}
```

My model:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

    class DetailsForRecipe: NSManagedObject {

        @NSManaged var name: String
        @NSManaged var ingredients: String
        @NSManaged var image: NSData

    }
```

The app should insert the ingredient name in the text field, save it into coreData, then it should be retrieved in the table view. When I text the ingredient name and press "add", the prinln message says it was successfully saved, but the table view does not update.

What am I doing wrong here? I'm not a developer, I've read many tutorials on how to do this, but it is very confusing! So forgive me about this.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't read your full source code, but by doing an immediate glance, I don't see that you've called the tableview's `reloadData` function. If you don't have an IBOutlet set up for your table view, you will want to do that and then call `reloadData()` on it.

Answer (score 0):

Call `reloadData()` on your table view after the change is made.

Comment: Where should I call reloadData()? In viewDidLoad it throws an error

Comment: I'm not sure how those two view controllers are related, but one way or another `SingleIngredientViewController` will have to call a method on `IngredientsViewController` that in turn calls `self.tableView.reloadData()`.  You could create a delegation relationship using a protocol  called `IngredientsViewControllerDelegate` with a method called `didAddDetail`, then have `IngredientsViewController` implement it and `SingleIngredientViewController` call it.